# Movable jquery box should not be moved out of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I'm creating a web application where I need to do some design tweaks. Here is the sample feature code: http://jsfiddle.net/rkumarnirmal/FSDPH/

The black movable box shown there should not be moved out of the page(not even a bit), but if you check there, You can move the box and place it somewhat out of the page. How can I control it?

One more thing, I'm going to implement jPicker tool http://www.digitalmagicpro.com/jPicker/ in that box. If we click the color box, the jPicker tool will be popped out and then if the box is moved the jPicker tool must have to arranged itself according to the page.

I know asking question like this is not fair, but I have no chance :( Could anyone guide me?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you should move the `jPicker` thing to a separate question. One question at one time. You can use `edit` under your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`containment`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#option-containment) property on `draggable` to keep the draggable element inside one of its parents.

For example:

```
$("#box_bg").draggable({scroll: false, cancel: "div#box", containment: 'document'});
```

Comment: Please check the code now http://jsfiddle.net/rkumarnirmal/FSDPH/2/ Dragging is not perfect.

Comment: It is perfect. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FSDPH/3/). Just removed your margins and replaced them with `top` and `left`.

Comment: One more help. In the box If you click the accordion headers you will find some selection border at the active accordion. How to remove that?

Comment: If you need to put this as a seperate question. then no problem, I will do it :)

Comment: @rnk You should ask a separate question, but even better, check the jQuery UI docs, I did the same myself. I would help but I'm going offline.

Answer (score 1):

Doing the whole code is not possible now. I'm giving you the logic. You can do it easily.

You have to track the overlay's drag event. Then in the event handler you have to check the left and top position of the overlay. If it goes beyond your limit then set left/top to 0 (or some offset).

On the other side if it goes beyond the extreme right (or bottom) you have to set the window's width (or height) minus the overlay's width (or height) accordingly.

same goes for the Color Picker. But instead of drag event you have to perform repositioning when the color picker is displayed.

Comment: I need your favor for one more problem. In the box If you click the accordion headers you will find some selection border at the active accordion. How to remove that?

Comment: I'm not able to see any extra border in active panel.
But if you see any extra border in your side you can remove it by css

#box_bg .ui-accordion-header.ui-state-active{
border:none;
}
You can apply any style here